# Android activities remain on stack even after OS kills application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-task

The problem: The application allows you to open a multitude of activities. Start application normally, open several activities then close app on HOME button. Use your phone, open other applications. In some moments Android OS kills application process and you can go to start again application. Start using it properly, open several activities and go back, back, back to close activities. When you close the last one, you can see the activities that you used previously.

First question: Why my activities stay in background after OS kill application?

Second question: How to solve this problem?

Comment: my crystal ball tells me that unless you provide a *question* and make some valid points, you will be severely downvoted and your "question" possibly closed in a few moments :)

Comment: Why to close question?

Comment: because there isn't any *question* in your diatribe. And by the way, I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: Is now better ? Do you have an answer on some of my questions?

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question. Can you explain a little better.

Comment: have you made any progress with this ? what solution have you used ?

Comment: This is native behavoir. In my case I had several activities, where you can open from one to another infinitely. My solution is, disallow user to open infinitely activities, can open several and go back for another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why my activities stay in background after OS kill application?

This is by design. In Android, an application never really dies, even if the containing process is killed. The application's last known state is saved by default, so that when the user returns to the app, he can resume from where he had previously left off.

> How to solve this problem?

First you need to think about whether this is really a problem. Since it is the default behavior, you have to consider what the framework designers had in mind when they programmed this behavior, and whether what *you* want is really appropriate for an Android application.

If you decide that it *is* an appropriate requirement for your app, then you can do one of two things:

**1.** Add

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch = true
android:excludeFromRecents = true
android:finishOnTaskLaunch = true
android:noHistory = true
```

to the root `Activity`'s tag in your app's manifest, and also add `android:noHistory = true` to **ALL** your `Activity` tags.

**2.** Start all your `Activity`s like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

This will essentially ensure that there is **NO** history at all for *any* of the app's `Activity`s.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this isn't solved my problem. First: noHistory in Manifest bad option for me, because I won't close activity each time. Second: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is API > 11, my Application support API 9 >...

Comment: 1 item - it what I need!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the home button does not close the application. The activities remain on the stack.

You can modify this behavior using launch modes.

Read more about [back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)  and [activity launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`
This will not create the activity instance in recent apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1.make a logo activity for main launcher. After logo activity create, will intent to target activity:

```
public class LogoActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context context = this;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

2. edit manifest, add android:launchMode="singleTask" for logo activity.
   example:

> ```
> <activity android:name=".LogoActivity"
>           android:launchMode="singleTask">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>     </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> ```

But this approach has a defect: when app launched from os desktop (without killed by os), it always re-open main activity.

Comment: Don't waste your time answering such old questions.